# Sorting a listbox, but keeping Items grouped together

Tags: vb.net

I have a question, I need to sort out items in a list box which I know how to do but the problem is, my listbox is sorted out like this

Person 1 firstname
Person 1 surname
Person 1 date
Person 1 gender
Person 1 address
Person 2 firstname
Person 2 surname
Person 2 date
Person 2 gender
Person 2 address
With each value being on a new line.
What I want is to keep each of the person's 5 details together and sort them by date, but I am not sure how to do that, as the only code I know to sort details mixes up all the data.

```
Private Sub btnSortDate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSortDate.Click
    Dim arr As New ArrayList
    Dim iLp As Integer

    arr.AddRange(lstFDisplay.Items)

    arr.Sort()

    lstFDisplay.Items.Clear()

    For iLp = 0 To arr.Count - 1
        lstFDisplay.Items.Add(arr(iLp))
    Next iLp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: You need to **separate your logic** (Your people, dates) from **your presentation** (What you're showing the user by putting in the list box). Something you should always avoid is displaying something (eg, showing the persons list) then *reading it back* and trying to make sense of it.

```
    Module MyForm
        ' Keep our dates & people in this dictionary
        ' Because it's a SortedDictionary, it'll keep them sorted by key
        '                                                key,     value
        Public personDictionary As New SortedDictionary(Of DateTime, Person)

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            ' Call CreatePeople() to fill our dictionary when the form is made
            CreatePeople()
            ' Then call FillListBox() to fill our listbox from that dictionary
            FillListBox()
        End Sub

        Private Sub CreatePeople()
            ' Make your persons and dates here
            Dim a = New Person(...)
            Dim dateA = New DateTime(2012,2,3)

            ' Keep them in our internal dictionary
            ' .Add(..) takes our key (a DateTime) and a value (a Person)
            personDictionary.Add(dateA, a)
        End Sub

        Private Sub FillListBox()
            lstFDisplay.Clear()

            ' Here we do something 'For Each' item in the dictionary
            ' The dictionary is filled with 'pairs' of key|value (DateTime|Person)
            For Each pair In personDictionary
                DateTime date = pair.Key
                Person person = pair.Value
                'Use this data to add items to our UI
                lstFDisplay.Items.Add("Name: "&person.Name
                lstFDisplay.Items.Add("Address: "&person.Address
                lstFDisplay.Items.Add(person.Name&" registered on "&date)
            Next
        End Sub
```

When you want to add or remove people, just `.Add(..)` or `.Remove(..)` from the dictionary and call `FillListBox()` again to refresh your UI. By keeping the values in the code itself, rather then re-reading it from the listbox every time, you have more control over how you handle that information.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I think you have more knowledge than me on vb, so thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this ok as a custom class, as I thought that is what might have been require.                                                    `Public Class Person  
    Public Property firstname As String  
    Public Property lastname As String  
    Public Property gender As String  
    Public Property applicationdate As Date  
    Public Property address As String  
    Public Sub New(ByVal firstname As String, Optional ByVal lastname As String = "None", Optional ByVal gender As String = "None", Optional ByVal applicationdate As Date = Nothing, Optional ByVal address As String = "None")`

Comment: `_firstname = firstname    
      _lastname = lastname    
      _gender = gender    
      _applicationdate = applicationdate    
      _address = address    
    End Sub    
      
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String    
      Return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Me.lastname, Me.firstname, Me.applicationdate)    
    End Function    
End Class`

Comment: That looks like what you'd need. Try putting a few of them into a new Dictionary(Of Date, Person) and calling .Sort() on it, then For Each through it and either add the properties manually, or the custom .ToString() that you set up, to the listbox's Items and that should be it.

Comment: This is the part I get confused with, I am not sure how to write it up, as I have been trying and getting no where.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to pick up enough VB to put together a working example ;)

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for the example unfortunately I am not 100% sure of what I am doing and I am only getting it to sort alphabetically, I am not quite sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code, so we might be able to give you direction on where you're going wrong?

Comment: I have the public class code I have above and what you showed me but I have nothing else as I have no idea what actually to do with any of it, I am totally new to vb and very confused. I will add what I have in my sort section now.